# Get paths from Illustrator file for overlay on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-illustrator

This is a pretty general question but just looking for someone to get me started in the right direction. I have been given a project where I need to create maps on a webpage and have certain parts of them highlighted/outlined on mouseover.

The maps I was given are illustrator files and when I open them up I see they are divided into the areas that I will need to highlight. Do I get those paths from AI and use them with something like Raphaël? Or do I create some overlays? Really not sure how to get started here.

Comment: I'd probably start with converting the AI file to SVG, and then try rendering that on a web page with Raphaël. You can then start adding JS events to get your mouseover effects.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator lets you export as svg. you can then use the svg as a background image, or include it inline in your page.

Note that you dont necessarily need to keep it in vector format in order to use it on a webpage. You could also simply use illustrator's "Save for web" feature to export the graphics as a png or gif.

Either way you can then start working with it like any normal web resource to build your page.